# How to plot an ellipse in to visualise an AFL field

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, ellipse

I'm just getting started playing around with R as I'm interested in doing some basic sport-related visualisations, and I'm stuck trying to plot an ellipse that will represent an AFL field.

I've currently plotted all of the landmarks and line markings inside of the field using ggplot2, and am using plotrix's draw.ellipse() to try and overlay the oval-shaped boundary line around the field. I only have the dimensions of the field which I can use to find the centre point of the ellipse and the radius of each arm of the ellipse.

```
xmin <- 0
xmax <- 17000
ymin <- 0
ymax <- 15000
```

But I would prefer to be able to use ggplot2 to draw the ellipse as I am more familiar with that package right now.

```
library(plotrix)
library(ggplot2)

field <- ggplot() + xlim(c(-10,xmax+10)) + ylim(c(-10,ymax+10))

oval <- draw.ellipse(c((xmax/2),(ymax/2)),a = (xmax/2), b = (ymax/2))
```

I want to plot the ellipse onto the blank canvas "field", which I can then overlay the other landmarks that I have already plotted, but currently am getting this error message:

```
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  invalid graphics state
2: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  invalid graphics state
```

Would it be simpler to create my own ellipse function and plot it using geom_path()? Or do I not have enough information to plot one?

## Follow Up

To follow up, I have all of the appropriate line markings plotted, for example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
xmin <- 0
xmax <- 17000
ymin <- 0
ymax <- 15000
fiftyarc_d <- 10000

circleFun <- function(centre=c(0,0),diameter=1,npoints=100){
  r = diameter/2
  tt <- seq(0,2*pi,length.out = npoints)
  xx <- centre[1] + r * cos(tt)
  yy <- centre[2] + r * sin(tt)
  return(data.frame(x = xx, y = yy))
}

field <- ggplot() + xlim(c(-10,xmax+10)) + ylim(c(-10,ymax+10))
oval  <- list(ggforce::geom_ellipse(aes(x0 = xmax/2, y0 = ymax/2, 
                                        a = 8000, b = 6000, angle = 0)))
fiftyarcleft <- circleFun(c(xmin,(ymax/2)),fiftyarc_d,npoints=100)

field + oval + geom_path(data=fiftyarcleft,aes(x=x,y=y))
```

I want to "cut" the arc segment that sits outside of the ellipse, there is one at each end of the x-axis. I have tried using

```
fiftyarcleft[which(fiftyarcleft$x >= oval)]
```

however I get an error that the object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: I wouldn't use `ggplot2` for this:  it is designed to plot data, not to draw specific diagrams.  You're better off using `grid` (which is used by `ggplot2`), or possibly base graphics (which is a mix of low-level graphics like `grid` and high level graphics like `ggplot2`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what dimensions you're going for (and it sounds like AFL dimensions vary, but this should be doable in `ggplot` and `ggforce::geom_ellipse`, like below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
xmin <- 0
xmax <- 17000
ymin <- 0
ymax <- 15000

field <- ggplot() + xlim(c(-10,xmax+10)) + ylim(c(-10,ymax+10))
oval  <- list(ggforce::geom_ellipse(aes(x0 = xmax/2, y0 = ymax/2, 
                                        a = 8000, b = 6000, angle = 0)))
field + oval
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Greatly appreciated.

Comment: See main post edit, everything is looking good but have run into trouble with the finishing touches.

Comment: You might need `geom_arc1 instead of `geom_ellipse` if you want a partial segment .